# Profiler showing sp_reset_connection when it's filtered out

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler

I created a new template with a TextData filter to not show sp_reset_connection statements in SQL Server 2012 profiler.
I restarted the profiler and used the new template. However the sp_reset_connection statements are still showing up.

Any ideas why?

[image]



[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try just `Not Like '%sp_reset_connection%'`? Also did you consider not using Profiler for tracing tasks? [Server-side traces have much lower impact than Profiler](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/sql-trace/observer-overhead-trace-extended-events).

Comment: I removed 'exec' but they still show up.

Comment: Do you have any other filters that we can't see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not include the '%' percent in your criteria. Just type in the exec sp_reset_connection as is.